# AWS Certificate Request Failing

Tags: ssl, certificate, amazon-web-services

I'm having some trouble requesting a certificate on AWS for a domain recently registered on Route 53. It was registered about two days ago now.

The domain is `cryptobase.cc`.

I've tried looking at their recommended [troubleshooting requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-requests.html#failed-domain-not-allowed) and checked both Google and PhishTank for any past violations to no avail.

I've only found one other mention of an issue like this on AWS forums [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=900834), also for a `.cc` domain. I tried to ask on there to the OP for updates but I have to wait some time before I can post.

The certificate is for `cryptobase.cc` and `*.cryptobase.cc` and I've successfully done this for two other domains.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

**Edit:**
In response to @Appleoddity, I'm using DNS verification and I have a hosted zone for `cryptobase.cc` on AWS Route 53. The error type is "Domain not allowed".

**Edit 2 (July 14th):**
Certificate request still failing with the same message after over a week of waiting. I've replied to the post mentioned above on AWS Forums to see if the OP ever resolved their issue.

Comment: What is the error you are receiving? Are you using email or DNS authorization to validate the domain?

Comment: Hi @Appleoddity, I've updated the post with the details.

Comment: I would try creating a certificate for just cryptobase.cc. You can delete it after. I wonder if a subdomajn of cryptobase.cc is being blocked that would match the wildcard cert. Try to narrow the problem down. Also, if it was a brand new domain that might be a problem. Have you tried deleting the carts all together and resubmitting? Are you sure you setup the domain in route 53 correctly with the cname?

Comment: Actually after looking up the domain I see it was created yesterday. I suspect you need to wait a period of time before you’ll be able to create a cert for this site.

Comment: Yes, I've tried resubmitting the certs and for just the domain itself. I think it's best to just wait a few more days. I'll keep the thread updated with my findings.

Comment: Regarding your question about the CNAME record, the process fails before it gives me the DNS records to add for verification. So it shouldn't be an issue with DNS.

Comment: Still not working, see edit 2.

Comment: Sorry, I think this is beyond what we are able to help with here. You’ll probably need to contact AWS support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered what the issue was after AWS support heard back from their internal ACM team - this took ages, not impressed.

Although not mentioned in the help documentation, AWS uses VirusTotal in addition to Phishtank and Google Safe Browsing to recognize malicious domains.

VirusTotal aggregates data from many vendors and so instead of contacting them directly, you have to resolve any false positives with each of the vendors individually. Just run a scan for your domain on their website and see which flag it as malicious. In my case, I had to get in touch only with ForcePoint.

Once this is sorted out, I should be able to successfully request the certificate for this domain.